# What is the fasted way to get the current file-name yank-able (with C-y)

Tags: emacs

Sometimes I edit files that have a certain suffix and files with same basename but another suffix. Since the basenames are long and awkward I would like to reuse the existing filename to construct the other name.

What I do currently is:

<kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> (This shows me the Buffer List)

<kbd>C-x o</kbd> (Now I am in the Buffer List)

<kbd>M-right M-left</kbd> (At the beginning of the basename)

<kbd>C-space M-right ... M-w</kbd> (Copying the basename)

<kbd>C-x o</kbd> (Back where I came from)

...

There must be a more canonical way to do this! (I am not interested in a way that involves the definition of a command proper, I have too many of them already...)

---

Edit: actually, what I wanted is to do something with that very name, most often create or read a related file. @Trey Jackson's <kbd>C-x C-v</kbd> is it!

Comment: Yes, the canonical way to do this is to define a command...

Comment: @TreyJackson: Making a command for every tiny operation only increases the setup-time you need on another person's emacs. Think of typing by telling ...

Comment: True, but if you're going to spend much time on someone else's Emacs, then it's good to learn about `emacs -u false` (assuming false is your user name).  Or, you can alway sstore your setup on github or a usb stick.  :)

Comment: @TreyJackson: Someone else's Emacs is typically a half-convinced student's Emacs. The argument: I can define it, if I want, doesn't work there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking this command does what you want, even if you don't want a command:

```
(defun copy-base-filename-as-kill ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename (buffer-file-name)))
    (when filename
      (kill-new (file-name-nondirectory (file-name-sans-extension filename))))))
```

But, if you're really just using this name to do something else... perhaps a better solution is to make doing that something else easier.

Try the command <kbd>C-x C-v</kbd> (aka <kbd>M-x find-alternate-file</kbd>) if what you want to do is create a new name based on the current name.

Comment: `C-x C-v` is **it**! Hero!

Comment: @false `(buffer-name)` is a lisp expression, you've got to do something with it.  Just doing `M-: (buffer-name)` doesn't give you anything to work with.

Comment: It's rather `C-u M-: (buffer-name)` in a scratch, but `C-x C-v` is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything out of the box that does it, but here's a little elisp function:

```
(defun copy-buffer-filename ()
  (when (buffer-file-name) 
    (kill-new (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))))
```